# can not compile project with android SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, unity-container, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to make an output for android tried various versions of android sdk and nothing.
i tried with api version 24 , 25 and 21 for android 5 and 7 but didnt compiled.
i am going frustrated.
any idea?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUq7V.jpg)

***error1*** :
Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
-bootclasspath "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Location-Based-Markerless-Augmented-Reality-master\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com\unity3d\player\R.java" "eu\kudan\androidar\R.java" "eu\kudan\ar\R.java"
warning: [options] source value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

***error2***:
UnityException: Resource compilation failed!
Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuildPointToConsole (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:271)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

**error3:**
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00207] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:172 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Java AND Android studio, then check that the different path to your SDKs are correct in Unity:
Edit > Preferences > External Tools

In my case the default paths work fine:
SDK : C:/Users/**NAME**/AppData/Local/Android/sdk
JDK : C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre
NDk : C:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r10e

Also rather use "/" instead of "\" in your paths.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have done all that and i have no trouble compiling other projects to android, just in augmented reality project i have this problem.